# Xetex and combining unicode characters

Tags: macros, xetex, unicode

I decided to use the combining over arrows like the ones in the following characters: Ω⃗,M⃗,B⃗,Ω⃡,E⃡.

I am using xelatex already because I need the unicode support for other sorts of characters.

However, `\newunicodechar{}{}` is proving to be a bit tricky and all I have managed to do is to put a rightwards or left-rightarrow to the right of the character that it's supposed to combine with.

I was hoping that there was a kind of command which:

1. displayed the characters like Ω⃡ correctly, even if I have to program it in for separate characters like Ω, B, M, ...
2. Doesn't leave a space after the character. For instance, Ω⃗₀ should not display with a space like in "Ω⃗ ₀".

Similar questions have been asked about pdf latex, but I was hoping there are better options since I am using xelatex and since I don't mind programming this in for individual characters.

*Ideally* the command would allow me to type something like Ω⃗ and take care of the display on its own.

Edit: thanks daleif for the input, here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{blindtext, hyperref, verbatim, minted, graphicx, amssymb, textcomp, enumerate, tcolorbox, newunicodechar, textgreek, wasysym, tipa, eso-pic, lipsum, bbold, dsfont}
\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newunicodechar{∂}{$\partial$}

\newunicodechar{×}{$\times$}
\newunicodechar{→}{$\rightarrow$}
\newunicodechar{⟨}{$\langle$}
\newunicodechar{⟩}{$\rangle$}
\newunicodechar{↦}{$->sto$}
\newunicodechar{∧}{$\wedge$}
\newunicodechar{∨}{$\vee$}
\newunicodechar{∃}{$\exists$}
\newunicodechar{∀}{$\forall$}
\newunicodechar{¬}{$\neg$}

\begin{document}

%LEAN: 
\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=5in,colback={white},title={\begin{center}\texttt{Lean \thelcounter} \addtocounter{lcounter}{1}  \end{center}},colbacktitle=Blue,coltitle=black]
\begin{minted}[breaklines, escapeinside=||||]{lean}

-- THIS HAS TO WORK: ∂⃗
def equal_arguments {X : Type} {Y : Type} {a : X} {b : X} (f : X → Y) (p : a = b) : f a = f b := congrArg f p

def equal_functions {X : Type} {Y : Type} {f₁ : X → Y} {f₂ : X → Y} (p : f₁ = f₂) (x : X) : f₁ x = f₂ x := congrFun p x

def pairwise {A : Type} {B : Type} (a₁ : A) (a₂ : A) (b₁ : B) (b₂ : B) (p : a₁ = a₂) (q : b₁ = b₂) : (a₁,b₁)=(a₂,b₂) := (congr ((congrArg Prod.mk) p) q)

\end{minted}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that you are always more likely to get help if you provide code (full but minimal exmaple). Then it is easier to understand what exactly you are doing.

Comment: as you have shown no source it is hard to say but you seem to be using this in math mode, which means Unicode combining characters are basically unsuportable.

Comment: Why not `\overrightarrow{Ω}_{0}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ideally the command would allow me to type the unicode (see last sentence for one of the only examples that needs to work, besides 12 others just like it). There is a good reason for that: I use \minted{}, which allows me to code python and several other unicode based programming languages inside the box. I explicitly want that as part of a workflow so I can run the latex and the code both at once. Hence the desire to be able to type, for an instance of one of the other 12,  ∂⃗ (which I also have as a macro).

Comment: So, what I want to ask is more like this: is there a way that I can type ∂⃗ inside \minted{} and it will display simply as the unicode?

Comment: By macro I mean the computer automatically replaces :par with ∂⃗.

Comment: that completely changes the question...I see you have added code. the code looks designed for pdftex rather than luatex eg why ∀ made active and turned to \forall rather than simply using ∀ with a unicode font?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this is xelatex and not luatex or pdftex. I use it because it has unicode support. Unicode fonts do not support such symbols as ॱ and , which I need (hence the xelatex). I run it as xelatex -shell-escape ThreeWhiteheadTheoremsMAIN.tex. The goal is to be able to type ∂⃗ inside the minted environment just like is possible for symbols like ∂ already.

Comment: you could use all the characters you show so far directly from a suitable font without using newinicodechar and an 7/8 bit math font, as you can see on this site and in your source view. you are using xetex but forcing all the symbols to come from 7 bit fonts with just 128 characters

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm really no expert in typesetting, could you explain what sort of font and command I could use, setting me up with a better font? I didn't know arial was limiting in this way. It would be especially nice if I didn't have to install a rare font for this.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I switched to DejaVu Sans and it worked-- thanks for your patience. There seems to be one remaining error which is that the combining over characters overlap with some of the capital letters such as Ω.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It seems to struggle with Ω⃗ and ∂⃗.

Comment: Looks like "STIX Two Text" renders it nicely.